# A is a square matrix where $3A^9- 7A^4 + 4A = I$. Prove that A is invertible by finding $A^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-equations

The question is:
A is a square matrix where $3A^9- 7A^4 + 4A = I$. Prove that A is invertible by finding A^-1.

I have looked at other similar questions on this site:
1. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628336/hermitian-matrix-such-that-4m52m3m-7i-n)
2. [and Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629760/how-prove-this-4a52a3a-7i)

But they use definitions and properties that I haven't been taught. Supposedly it can be proven using the definitions we already have gotten.

We have learned nothing of eigenvalues yet, thought we have learned a little about determinants.

I have a rather dull solution but I don't think it is correct:

$3A^9- 7A^4 + 4A = I$

$3A^9- 7A^4 + 4A = A* A^{-1}$

$A^{-1}(3A^9- 7A^4 + 4A) = A^{-1}*A* A^{-1}$

$3A^8- 7A^3 + 4*I = A^{-1}$

From here it can be seen that if we multiply $A^{-1}$ by A we get the original definition given to us equivalent to I. Q.E.D.

I'm sure there is a better solution than this since it feels that this solution is not good since it works off of the assumption that A is invertible. A*A^-1 = I.

We haven't learned anything about Hermitian matrices so it would be helpful to try to solve this using basic inverse matrix definitions.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you should have $A^{-1}$ on the right in the left-hand side of your third line of work. Notice that a far simpler method, with the same result, is basically used in your solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Woah.  You're definitely overthinking here.

$M_n(R)$ is a ring for any other ring $R$, so we have the distributive property.  (You can show this manually).  Therefore, we have:

$$3A^9 -7A^4 + 4A = A(3A^8 - 7A^3 + 4) = I$$

And so...

Comment: That's similar to my answer, but how does that prove definitively that A is invertible?

Comment: $A^{-1} = 3A^8 - 7A^3 + 4$

Comment: This is the same answer I got, but I assumed it was incorrect since it works off of the assumption that A is invertible (i.e. $A * A^{-1} = I$. So, just to double check, my answer is correct?

Comment: @Klik, you are correct that your proof kind of begs the question regarding the invertibility of $A$.  At any rate, you should make sure to be consistent when you multiply on both sides in the third line of work.  In the world of non-commutative rings, there can be a difference between multiplying on the left as opposed to on the right.

Comment: @Klik, I think your answer is wrong as you *use* $\;A^{-1}\;$ before even being sure it exists: when you write $\;I=AA^{-1}\;$ this is justified **only** if we know $\;A^{-1}\;$ exists, to begin with. The above answer does the right think and shows that there exists $\;B\;$ s.t. $\;AB=I\;$ . *This* solves the problem. +1

Comment: OH I SEE! Thanks for clearing that up @Timbuc. Since we can see that it EXISTS we know it is invertible. I understand your solution now Kaj, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Glad we could help!